# Woocommerce Hide coupon field by Payment at Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I already hide the coupon field on the cart page. Now I try to hide or show the coupon field depending on the payment method at the checkout page.

I tried this code: [Woocommerce Payment Method Detection in Checkout Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930063/woocommerce-payment-method-detection-in-checkout-page)

But it won't work. Do you have any hints for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share your tried code?

Comment: I tried the code I mentioned above including the function hide_coupon_field_on_checkout but it still not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use woocommerce 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled' action hooks. Try below code

```
function hide_coupon_field_on_checkout( $enabled ) {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_checkout' );
```

Comment: thank you for that code. I know that already. So I want this action depending on payment method