# How to define payment gateway based custom price per product in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price, woocommerce-theming

I want to set custom price per product based on selected payment gateway. For an example:

```
Cash price - 1000
Visa Master - 1100
PayPal - 1250
```

Likewise I want to show different price based on selected payment gateway. Also, I want to show lowest price as starting price for particular product when browsing the website.

Currently I have define the upper limit price and giving discount based on the selected payment method. But I don't like that way because when browsing it is showing the upper limit price instead of lowest price for users who are browsing. As this this example it is showing `1250` for user's who are browsing the website. Instead `1250` I want to show starting at `1000`.

Hope you can help me out on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce Payment Method Detection in Checkout Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930063/woocommerce-payment-method-detection-in-checkout-page)

Comment: This solves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152363/8298248 Once the payment method is detechted in the backend just update the total according to the your logic.

Comment: @bhanu thank you for your reference. But I am bit confused about how the code should use in my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use woo discount rules, with product adjusment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).